# HashMap Duplicate Values - Identify the duplicates

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I understand that `HashMap` doesn't allow insertion of duplicate values and it replaces the last duplicate value with the latest entry.
Is there a way to print the duplicates which were found during the `put` method?

I have the following code snippet:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++) {
    nodeDBList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(elements[i]).evaluate(dbDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int j = 0; j < nodeDBList.getLength(); j++) {
        if(nodeDBList.item(j).getFirstChild() != null)
            dbList.put(nodeDBList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().toLowerCase().trim(), 
                       nodeDBList.item(j).getNodeName().toLowerCase().trim());

    }
}
```

Comment: by values, you mean keys?

Comment: override the HashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old value of the key is returned by the put method, so you can output it.

Assuming the value of your `HashMap` is of type `String` :

```
for( int i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++)
{
    nodeDBList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(elements[i]).evaluate(dbDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int j = 0; j < nodeDBList.getLength(); j++) {
        if(nodeDBList.item(j).getFirstChild() != null) {
            String oldVal = dbList.put(nodeDBList.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().toLowerCase().trim(), nodeDBList.item(j).getNodeName().toLowerCase().trim());
            if (oldVal != null) {
                System.out.println(oldVal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the above code snippet serves my purpose. Thanks a million Eran.

Answer (score 5):

Wrong. `HashMap` does not support duplicate keys, which are hashed.

Duplicate values are totally acceptable for different keys.

You can search for existing values by iterating them through the `values()` method and using the `equals` method.

**Edit**

There seems to be a confusion between keys and values here.

According to the `HashMap` implementation of `Map`'s `public V put(K key, V value);`, the method `put` will return the original value for a given key if any, or `null`.

**Quote from the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)**

> @return the previous value associated with key, or null if there was
>   no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key.)

Comment: I believe, when we try to insert a duplicate value, hashmap internally checks if thats a duplicate and allows the latest value. I need to print all those duplicate values encountered during the .put method. Is there a way to print them?

Comment: I actually have a key (which is the xml node) and multiple values associated with the key. I can see that any duplicate values are currently ignored and the last one(from the duplicate values) gets added to the map.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the answer can be found in [the API description of HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-): The put method returns the value that was previously associated with the key.

> **Returns**:
>       the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key.)

Answer (score 1):

Override the HashMap

this is an example

```
public class MyMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K,V> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1006394139781809796L;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return super.put(key, value);
        }
        if (value.getClass() == Timestamp.class) {
            DateFormat dateTimeFormatter;
            dateTimeFormatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, getLocale());
            super.put((K) (key + "_f"), (V) dateTimeFormatter.format(new Date(((Timestamp) value).getTime())));

            DateFormat dateFormatter;
            dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, getLocale());
            super.put((K) (key + "_f_date"), (V) dateFormatter.format(new Date(((Timestamp) value).getTime())));

        } 
        if (value.getClass() == java.sql.Date.class) {
            DateFormat dateFormatter;
            dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, getLocale());
            super.put((K) (key + "_f"), (V) dateFormatter.format(new Date(((java.sql.Date) value).getTime())));
        } 
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
}
```